# logic gates problem

Tags: logic-gates

[image]
Can some one tell me why my xor gate is acting like an and gate?

Comment: Try to post schematics rather than breadboard diagram. This is hardly recognisable.

Answer (score 2):

Pin 1 is wired permanently low (you tapped the wrong side of the resistor), so I'd *expect* it to act like a buffer amplifier for the other input: the output will be controlled by switch 1 alone, and ignore switch 2.

Comment: Thank you Sir! I am sorry if the mistake was banal but I am a beginner. I wish you a good weekend!